# Tough Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I got a skill test for a quick mysql query. I am given the tables:

```
    Orders                    OrderItems
----------------------------------------                
    id                         id
    date                       order_id(Orders.id)
    shipping_amount            product_id
    order_status               price
    customer_id             quantity
```

I need to show Orders id and totals (including shipping amount) and records prior to June 1, 2003.

output should be...

```
| OrderID   | OrderTotal |
+-----------+------------+
| 13230     | $55.00     |
| 54455     | $40.00     |
| 59694     | $33.04     |
| 39495     | $21.05     |
```

The hint is to use Group by or subselect. I have the following statement so far but not sure what to do next.

```
Select id AS OrderId,***(not sure what to do here) 
from Orders join OrderItems on Orders.id=OrderItems.id
```

Comment: Whose skills are being tested here?

Comment: Why not show how you can get all the order totals, so each order id will have several totals. Then, once you show that, it may make more sense to help guide you, but, have you read the mysql manual on select statements? This is a test after all.

Comment: I understand the test is the test. I do write mysql query very often, but I just haven't had chances to work on this kind of complex query. I was hoping to get few tips on this question. Thanks for the advise though...I will definitely  read manual

Comment: While to try an write the query as you understand it and you all know where your mistake lie when corrected. Remember it's your skill that is been tested. Don't worry every error is a goood lesson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to a mysql database to test, but I would imagine it looks something like this:

```
select
  o.id OrderID,
 (select sum(oi.price * oi.quantity) from order_items oi where oi.order_id = o.id) + o.shipping_amount OrderTotal
from
  orders o
where
  o.date < str_to_date('2003-06-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: It happens that MySQL dates accept YYYY-MM-DD, so you don't need to worry about parsing it.

Comment: @Charles: You can't assume that is the format someone will use - explicitly converting to a DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP is the safest approach.  +1, Brandon

Comment: OKay, in this *specific* case, you don't need to worry about parsing it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it must look like this:

```
SELECT O.ID as OrderID, SUM(OI.price * OI.quantity) AS OrderTotal 

FROM Orders O 

INNER JOIN OrderItems OI ON O.id = OI.order_Id

WHERE date < '2003-06-01'

GROUP BY O.id

ORDER BY SUM(price * quantity) DESC
```

Not sure how to format dates in MySQL though or if you can order by an agregate function in this version but I'm pretty sure this is a good start.

Comment: +1: Assuming the OP wants to see orders where the ordertotal is zero, change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and use COALESCE to change the NULL into zero.

Comment: It'll get easier once you do a few queries :)

Comment: I think this the best answer based on the problem description assuming the price is per item. But if the price is the total cost of quantity, then do not multiply the quantity by price