# Mysql Query: error that says subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to do a complex query from two tables...It's a question from a skill quiz.

table

```
**Orders                                    Customer**s
    id                                         id
    date                                     first_name
    shipping_amount                          last_name 
    order_status                             city
    customer_id (Customers.id)             state
```

output

```
-----------+------------+
| State     |  # Orders  |
+-----------+------------+
| NY        |  55        |
| CA        |  40        |
| NJ        |  33        |
| FL        |  21        |
| MO        |  12        |
+-----------+------------+
```

I have been working on my query and it looks like this...

```
select DISTINCT state, (select count(id) Orders
                        from customers
                        group by state
                        ORDER BY Orders DESC) FROM Customers
```

It gave me an error that says subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340079/tough-mysql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.state, COUNT(o.id) AS Orders 
FROM Customers c, Orders o 
WHERE o.customer_id = c.id 
GROUP BY state 
ORDER BY Orders DESC
```

The sub query isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Customers`.`state`, count(`Orders`.`id`) 
as `orders FROM `Customers` 
LEFT JOIN `Orders` ON `Customers`.`id` = `Orders`.`customer_id` 
GROUP BY `Customers`.`state` 
ORDER BY `orders` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT state, (select count(id) as cnt, Orders from customers group by
    state ORDER BY Orders DESC) Temp FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.state as State, COUNT(o.id) as NumOrders
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN customers c ON (c.id = o.customer_id)
GROUP BY c.state
```